# Send Cloud Storage trigger notifications to client app

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

My React Native Expo app uses images fetched from a Cloud Storage bucket. Once the images are fetched the first time, I cache the images so the images don't have to be retrieved each time. However these images could get updated once in a while, and I want to notify the client of the same, so that particular image can be updated automatically.

I have created a cloud function that is triggered when there is a file uploaded/modified on Cloud Storage. (I also have a Flask backend, but was not able to integrate it there). The function looks somewhat like this

```
def image_update(event, context):
  print('Event ID: {}'.format(context.event_id))
  print('Event type: {}'.format(context.event_type))
  print('Bucket: {}'.format(event['bucket']))
  print('File: {}'.format(event['name']))
  print('Metageneration: {}'.format(event['metageneration']))
  print('Created: {}'.format(event['timeCreated']))
  print('Updated: {}'.format(event['updated']))
  return event['name']
```

I want to return the file name that is updated (as you can see above) to the client, but I'm not sure how to do so. I try to send a get/post request to the URL of the format http://REGION_NAME-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNC_NAME (which works for HTTP functions, but this is not one, so not sure about it), but it doesn't work.

How could I notify the client (through an HTTP request or something similar) of an update in the storage bucket?

Answer (score 0):

If sounds like you're looking for the [Object Finalize trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#object_finalize), which is run each time a file in your bucket is written. The name of the file that was written in in the `event['name']` field.

The common way to information your client-side application of changes would be through Firebase Cloud Messaging. This allows you to send a message to the app, even when the user is not actively using the app. The app can then either immediately download the new image, or (more likely) remove the outdated image from its cache to download the new versio when the user accesses it next time.

Alternatively you could write the modified image path to a database (such as Cloud Firestore) and then load the list of modified images from the database when the app starts.

Comment: Thank you, I am indeed using the Object Finalize trigger, but wasn't able to figure out a way to pass it on to the client. I will look into FCM.